# How to get created date of pin from pintererst using api?

Tags: php, api, pinterest

This is my code which will get the pin info:

```
get_curl_data('https://api.pinterest.com/v1/pins/431430839282408407/?access_token=XXXXX',true);
```

I am using the pinterest API to get Pins , And I am getting the pins and board information, but Ii am not getting the created date of Pin. How can I get the created date of the pin? Is it possible to get the date? I searched and also read the Pinterest Official documentation for the API but there is no info for created date of pin. I also searched on google but I didn't find any information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short: You need to add a fields parameter which includes "created_at": https://api.pinterest.com/v1/pins/431430839282408407/?access_token= XXXXX&fields=created_at

Long: At the page https://developers.pinterest.com/tools/api-explorer/ select the box "Pins" and choose "Return information about a Pin". You will see a Fields section, where you can select "created_at". Fill in a pin id and a access token and the response of the request will have the information you are looking for.